# Truth table to prove an argument true/false

Tags: truthtable

Can someone help me out with truth tables? I would like to create a truth table to prove whether or not this is true.

Comment: Is this homework? If so, please tag it so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
A  B  C    B∧C   A∨(B∧C)  A ∨ B   A ∧ C    (A ∨ B) ∨ (A ∧ C)
0  0  0     0       0        0        0               0
0  0  1     0       0        0        0               0
0  1  0     0       0        1        0               1 
0  1  1     1       1        1        0               1 
1  0  0     0       1        1        0               1
1  0  1     0       1        1        1               1
1  1  0     0       1        1        0               1
1  1  1     1       1        1        1               1
```

When A=0, B=1 and C=0

```
A ∨ (B ∧ C) = 0
(A ∨ B) ∨ (A ∧ C) = 1 ∨ 0 = 1
```

So A ∨ (B ∧ C) = A ∨ B) ∨ (A ∧ C) is false.

Comment: Awesome! so 0 being false and 1 being true?

Answer (score 0):

```
A = 0, B = 0, C = 0
A ∨ (B ∧ C) = 0 ∨ (0 ∧ 0) = 0 ∨ 0 = 0
(A ∨ B) ∨ (A ∧ C) = 0
```

Do the similar for the 7 more combination of A, B and C.

```
A = 0, B = 0, C = 1
A = 0, B = 1, C = 0
//// etc.
```

If you find both end same for all the eight then that is proved. Otherwise the are not same.

Also visit the [Wikipedia entry for truth table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table) for the details. Application section contains an example proof of another equation.

Note: Sounds like a homework. So not providing the full solution.

Comment: thx, this is actually for demonstration that I need to present to co-workers.. Unfortunately I am not that hip on truth tables so that makes it a bit difficult :)

Comment: Cheek the Wikipedia link that I have added. That may help you further.

Answer (score 0):

You only have three boolean variables, which means a 2^3=8 entry truth table will suffice. I suggest breaking down columns in your table to produce one boolean result at a time. If the two columns of the two sides of your boolean equation match, them you proved they are the same, otherwise you will have one or more counter-examples.

If the two expressions match, then you can try to prove they are equal using the rules of Boolean algebra. Karnaugh maps could even be used to point the way.